# Using a JSON array received as a string

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm receiving a string, `output`, that looks like this:

```
{family_name:XXX, given_name:XXX, locale:en, name:XXX, picture:XXX, profile:XXX, sub:XXX}
```

I'd like to get some of these values and store them in variables, but since it's a string I cant use indexing (I would've just used `var x = output[0]` etc)

How would I get a hold of these values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `json.net` to deserialize the json string into an object (the easy way), or the classes in `Newtonsoft.Json.linq` to parse it manually.

Comment: You will have to de-serialize the string using a json parser such as json.net or javascriptserializer provided with .net framework.

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: A JSON string would have quotes around the names and values.  Have you removed those quotes or are they not there? http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf  This question covers answers regarding C# https://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165/125981

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the string is a JSON-object. Therefore, you must handle it as a JSON-object.
First parse it to JSON. eg. like this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(YOUR_STRING);
```

And now to get the given value you wish, for instance `family_name` you can say:

```
string name = (string) json["family_name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend Json.Net.

Parse your string to json, and create a model that can hold those JSON values as

```
public class Person
{
    public string family_name {get;set}
    public string given_name {get;set;}
    public List<string> siblings{get;set;}
}
```

(This could be done with https://quicktype.io/csharp/ or manually)

Then:

```
string json = @"{
  'family_name': 'Foo',
  'given_name': 'Bar',
  'siblings': [
    'Jhon',
    'Doe'
  ]
}";

Person person = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(json);

string familyName = person.family_name;
//Foo
```